# what does 'the roll of duck tape' mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

what does '**the roll of duck tape**' mean ? 
Would you please give me some examples to know how to use it?

Comment: Duck tape is a brand of [duct tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duct_tape).

Comment: http://www.cyclelicio.us/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/flowchart.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duck tape (sometimes called "duct" tape) is a very strong adhesive tape that is almost legendary for having so many uses.

It is very adhesive, and very strong.

As with most adhesive tapes, it is sold wound up on a roll, so a roll of duck tape is exactly what it says: a wound up amount of ready-to-use very strong and versatile adhesive tape.

I propose you use [Google](http://www.scotchducttape.com/gallery?WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=SE_SDTCP_duck-tape-crafts) to find out about the many, many uses for it. You may find that people use it for such diverse purposes as making wallets out of it to hanging people on walls or trees.